# CakePHP Automagic Form Helper with Associations

Tags: php, cakephp, form-helpers

I have two CakePHP models, Tests and Questions, where a Test has many questions, and a Question only has one test.

Neither this code:

```
echo $form->create("Question", array('action' => 'add'));
echo $form->input("text");
echo $form->input("Test.id", array( 'value' => $test['Test']['id']  , 'type' => 'hidden') ); 
echo $form->end("Add");
```

Nor:

```
echo $form->create("Question", array('action' => 'add'));
echo $form->input("text");
echo $form->input("Question.Test.id", array( 'value' => $test['Test']['id']  , 'type' => 'hidden') ); 
echo $form->end("Add");
```

associates the new question with a test (but does create it in the database).

$test['Test']['id'] does produce a correct output of ID.

Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should associate (if you haven't done it yet) the two models with `hasOne` and `hasMany` associations and doing so creating in the table `questions` a column called `test_id` (that's named *foreignKey*).

The form of the question then becomes:

```
echo $form->create("Question", array('action' => 'add'));
echo $form->input("text");
echo $form->input("Question.test_id", array( 'value' => $test['Test']['id']  , 'type' => 'hidden') ); 
echo $form->end("Add");
```

Comment: Whilst I'd done the association already (with hasOne/hasMany), thanks for noting, as may be useful for those with issues in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Your naming is off. You should call your hidden field Question.test_id instead, since that is the field where the value should be saved. For example:

```
$this->Form->input('Question.test_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $test['Test']['id']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old, but for those who came here like me looking for CakePHP 3 answers, the association naming convention for inputs has changed, with `table.field` for BelongsTo/HasOne associations and `tables.field` for HasMany/BelongsToMany associations.

Read [the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) for more info.